# How can a command line tool print the help text and automatically get the behavior with piping to the more command?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

With the command line tools I've built with Swift in Xcode there is an option to print the help text. When there is more text than the height of the terminal window it scrolls past the start of the help text. When viewing man pages the text is automatically paged like it is using the `more` command.

Is there a way to get this behavior with a command line tool built in Xcode?